# mysqli persistent connection

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

In short, is there some sort of `mysqli_pconnect` for high-usage `PHP` & `MySQL` servers, or do I need to stick with `mysql` unimproved? And if so, why did they remove it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Support for this was introduced in PHP 5.3. For versions before this, PDO and – god forbid – the mysql extension are the only options.

To quote the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php):

> Unlike the mysql extension, mysqli does not provide a separate function for opening persistent connections. To open a persistent connection you must prepend p: to the hostname when connecting.

Answer (score 8):

Actually there is [persistent support](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php) for mysqli library. Just prepend "p:" to the hostname and you're done.

Comment: how do you prepend "p:" to the host name? example:    $this->mysqli = new mysqli(mysql_host,mysql_user,mysql_password,mysql_database);

Comment: @JavaNewb: sorry for resurrecting an old thread, but we left a question unanswered! I "prepend p:" with string concatenation. Example: $this->mysqli = new mysqli('p:'. mysql_host, mysql_user, mysql_password, mysql_database);

Comment: @SteveAlmond How does your comment add anything more to the answer?  He already said about prepending `p:` to the hostname, and the answer has not been edited.