# How to keep a mysql connection alive in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script which loops over tables and fields doing a find and replace.  The script takes around 4 minutes to complete.  The database is about 1.5GB.

The problem is that I am somehow loosing the database connection.  I am using ADODB to connect to mySQL.  The db connection is opened at the beginning and remains open the whole duration of the script.

The problem disappears when I use the following code:

```
if ($rowCount % 100000 == 0) {
    $db->Execute('USE ' . $db->database);
}
```

I am not a fan of this solution!

Any suggestions/explanations/discussions that help me to stop scratching my head would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is it your server or are you able to edit its configuration? You may run into [mysql.connect_timeout](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.configuration.php#ini.mysql.connect-timeout)

Comment: set_time_limit(0); It's not your php script timing out is it?

Comment: The script runs on many servers.  Some of which I have control.  It would be nice to handle any configuration from within the script. @Eddie - the script is not timing out.

Comment: What errors do you get? I assume you are running with error_reporting(E_ALL) and logging errors, and enabling any error handling in the ADODB library?

Answer (score 2):

The word you're looking for is 'persistent', and the answer you're looking for is here:

[mysqli persistent connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479537/mysqli-persistent-connection)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `mysql_pconnect();` or equally for ADODB `$conn->PConnect();` to create a persistent connection

Comment: It is not necessary or desirable to use persistent connections to maintain a connection *within one page*. Persistent connections are generally undesirable

Comment: @MarkR Do you have any other suggestions on how to maintain connection?

Comment: `mysql_pconnect` is now deprecated - please use an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Use [mysqli::ping()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.ping.php) to determine if connection is alive. Connect again if not.

> Checks whether the connection to the server is working. If it has gone
>   down, and global option mysqli.reconnect is enabled an automatic
>   reconnection is attempted.
>
> This function can be used by clients that remain idle for a long
>   while, to check whether the server has closed the connection and
>   reconnect if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of these methods to make a persistent connection to mysql:

### Mysqli

Try using `mysqli_connect()` with `p:` prefix for host name.

### PDO

Try using `PDO::__construct()` with `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT` as a driver option.